# Extract time zone from jodatime DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I receive a datetime string containing an ISO8601 datetime, like this `"2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00"`, then this string is parsed to a jodatime datetime object this way `new DateTime("2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00")`, and after that it is converted to a string again using a variable formatter pattern passed by arguments, but when that happens, no timezone is used, so the system's default timezone is being used. What I want is to extract the timezone (or offset) from the first given date, and use it to print it accordingly. Is it possible?

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Can you show the code where this reconversion to a String happens? Because what you propose looks like a workaround and I'm pretty certain a real solution exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `new DateTime("...")`. Use `DateTime.parse("...")`.

See difference:

```
DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime("2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00");
System.out.println(dateTime1);
System.out.println(dateTime1.getZone());

DateTime dateTime2 = DateTime.parse("2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00");
System.out.println(dateTime2);
System.out.println(dateTime2.getZone());
```

*Output (I'm in eastern US)*

```
2001-07-04T15:08:56.235-04:00
America/New_York
2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00
-07:00
```

As you can see, using `new` converts to default time zone, while using `parse` retains the given time zone.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! It actually works nice. The only little thing I see is that it converts time zone information from ID to offset, and so, when I use the `z` pattern to print the time zone, I get its numerical representation (-07:00) instead of its name (EDT or Eastern Daylight Time). Do you know any way to get the name instead?

Comment: @beni0888 there is more than one time zone with -07:00 offset. If you want the zone to be displayed by name, you'll have to provide that name.